# How to edit a config in about:config via command line WITHOUT having to restart Firefox to have it applied?

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to automate a process and want to edit a config in about:config via command line WITHOUT having to restart Firefox to have it applied. How can I do that?

I'm under Linux. I tried editing the file `/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/id.default/prefs.js` but obviously the settings are not applied in real time but a restart is needed.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Even if you change the setting via a command, if the setting requires the process to be restarted to take effect, you won't be able to avoid restarting the process.

Comment: @Ramhound I know that, but the setting that I want to change does not require Firefox to be restarted.